# Generation of Interquartile Positions With Increasing Depth

Tags: java, iqr

I wanted to generate the interquartile (IQR) positions programmatically so that I could use them as a basis for obtaining values within a min - max range, with increasing orders of granularity.

I got stuck on this for a while. Surprisingly, when I was looking for ideas, I found nothing on Stack Overflow. Because of that, I'll post the solution I came up with in order to help people in the future if they need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
final int DEPTH = 32 //2^n where n is the depth of the quartile tree

for(int j = 1; j < DEPTH; j *= 2){
    double quotient = 1.0 / j;   //How many quartiles to generate

    for(int i = 1; i < j; ++i)
        if(i % 2 != 0)
            System.out.println((i * quotient));
    System.out.println("-------");
}
```

Doing this gives the following output:

```
-------
0.5
-------
0.25
0.75
-------
0.125
0.375
0.625
0.875
-------
0.0625
0.1875
0.3125
0.4375
0.5625
0.6875
0.8125
0.9375
-------
```